# Condition of linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

[Theorem on linear independence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hooNk.png)

How would one go about proving the second part of the if and only if  theorem in the above  link?
I have proved the first half that is if S is linearly independent it cannot have any vector be spanned by the vectors listed before it,but I can't find a logical reason to prove the converse of this(ie. if for all vectors v in S , if v is not spanned by the vectors listed before it , it is linearly independent).

Comment: This isn't a theorem, it's a definition. You don't prove it, you accept it as the meaning of the words "linearly independent".

Comment: But I am unable to relate this statement or definition with other definitions., which are more general than this

Comment: What other definitions would you like to relate it to?

Comment: @ziggurism It can be used as definition, but I think that here it is a theorem after all. It might be that it must be proved on base of a definition like: "$v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent if the equality $\lambda_1v_1+\cdots+\lambda_nv_n=0$ implies that $\lambda_i=0$ for every $i$"

Comment: @drhab  , Right!      [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cfmM.png)
, I am asked to prove this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: use induction on $k$.

Induction step:

Suppose that $v_1,\dots,v_{k-1}$ are linearly independent and that $v_k\notin\text{span}(\{v_1,\dots,v_{k-1}\})$.
Now try to prove that under these conditions also $v_1,\dots,v_{k-1},v_k$ are linearly independent.